# Как заставить код возвращать Unit, а не String (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть такой код, собранный из кусков кода Kotlin по гуглу. По идее, в итоге я должен получать файл `jjj.txt` (предпоследняя строка) c записанными построчно путями ко всем файлам в папке `/0/storage/emulated/tmp`. Споткнулся на том, что первый фрагмент выводит то, что мне надо записать в jjj.txt, через println. Как сделать, чтобы то, что выводится через println, записывалось в jjj.txt (т. е. передавалось в `FileWriter("/0/storage/emulated/jjj.txt").use { it.write(paths) }`)?

```
fun getAllFilesInResources()
{
    val projectDirAbsolutePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
    val resourcesPath = Paths.get(projectDirAbsolutePath, "/0/storage/emulated/tmp")
    val paths = Files.walk(resourcesPath)
        .forEach { item -> println("filename: $item") }

    FileWriter("/0/storage/emulated/jjj.txt").use { it.write(paths) }
}
```

Речь идёт об Android

Comment: Вам нужно переосмыслить подход. Пусть в этом коде будет создаваться объект того фрагмента, в котором выводится, а в том фрагменте создайте метод, который будет возвращать строку для записи. Таким образом в этом коде, используя созданный объект, мы будем обращаться к методу, возвращающему строку и записывать эту строку.

Comment: Что-то заголовок никак не стыкуется с телом вопроса...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно как-то так надо?

```
fun getAllFilesInResources() {
    val projectDirAbsolutePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
    val resourcesPath = Paths.get(projectDirAbsolutePath, "/0/storage/emulated/tmp")
    val paths = Files.walk(resourcesPath)

    FileWriter("/0/storage/emulated/jjj.txt").use {
        paths.forEach { item -> it.write("filename: $item\n") }    
    }
}
```